# Non-Serializable Object exception

Tags: java, serialization, memcached

I am trying to set a list of  objects(serializable)  in Memcached client. I am doing it using the  set method.   I am getting this error message:

> Exception occurred in target VM: Non-serializable object

So it's not allowing me to set the value in the `MemcachedClient` object. Here's my code:

```
MemcachedClient client = CacheConnectionUtil.connectToCacheServer(this.applicationEnv);
client.set(generateCacheKey(namespace, key), expireInSeconds, value);
// value is a list of objects that implements serializable
```

Why am I getting this error message?

Comment: Does your object have implements Serializable ?

Comment: yes it implements Serializable,  added code in post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Serializable` javadocs:

> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the `Serializable` interface. In this case the `NotSerializableException` will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object.

Memcached seems to be hiding the rest of the exception message, so you'll have to identify the non-serializable object yourself.

You say that `values` is a list of your own object. My guess is your object holds something that isn't also `Serializable`, or it holds something that *holds something else* that isn't `Serializable`. Go through the class of the objects in your list and make sure that every object underneath it implements `Serializable`.

As an example, if I have `A` implements `Serializable`:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    private B b;
    // ...
}
```

And `B` doesn't:

```
public class B { ... }
```

Then any attempt to serialize `A` using an `ObjectOutputStream` (which is probably what the default serializer in the Memcached library is doing) will throw a `NotSerializableException` because its field, `private B b`, is a non-serializable type, which is what you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. The problem was one of the object's related class was not Serializable.

Comment: This helped me to solve the issue I was facing. For the JMS message type, the field classes were not serializable. I implemented Serializable interface and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe an object inside your `MemcachedClient` class can't be serialized. You have 2 options to solve the problem:

1. Make sure all the classes there implement the `Serializable` interface.

   ```
   public class MemcachedClient {

       //AnotherClass must implement Serializable too.
       private AnotherClass anotherClassInstance;
   }
   ```
2. If the other class doesn't implement `Serializable` (and you can't modify those classes to make them `Serializable`), then add the `transient` keyword so those objects won't be serialized

   ```
   public class MemcachedClient {

       //AnotherClass doesn't implement Serializable.
       private transient AnotherClass anotherClassInstance;
   }
   ```

If you must have an instance of `AnotherClass` when you deserialize your `MemcachedClient` object, then you can write the `readObject(ObjectInputStream is)` to create an instance based on the needs:

```
public class MemcachedClient {

    //AnotherClass doesn't implement Serializable.
    private transient AnotherClass anotherClassInstance;

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        os.defaultWriteObject();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        is.defaultReadObject();
        anotherClassInstance = new AnotherClass();
        //more logic to get a consistant AnotherClass instance.
    }
}
```

---

Based in Brian's comment, assuming this `MemcachedClient` class is from a third party library and you can't modify it, you would have an scenario like described in point 2:

```
public class MyClass {

    //MemcachedClient can't be modified and doesn't implement Serializable interface
    //the only solution would be using the transient modifier
    private transient MemcachedClient memcachedClient;

    //MyClass attributes and methods...

    //If you need to keep a MemcachedClient instance when deserializing the object
    //just write the readObject method

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        os.defaultWriteObject();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        is.defaultReadObject();
        memcachedClient= new MemcachedClient();
        //more logic to get a consistant MemcachedClient instance.
    }
}
```

Comment: `MemcachedClient` is from a [third party library](http://dustin.github.com/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.html), and the class itself is unrelated to his actual problem

Comment: @Brian in case this is OP's problem, then the theory and examples placed in my answer would help him/her to solve the real problem (that's not posted anywhere).

Comment: Absoultely, agreed, so your answer should be more generic instead of using the `MemcachedClient` class, to keep from confusing the OP and other users that find your answer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your objects implements `Serializable` (and even all the objects referred from your objects)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with serializing lists. My issue turned out to be that I was using List.subList, and even though the List only contains serializable items, the List returned by subList was not serializable. A quick solution was to do something like

```
List mySublist = new ArrayList().addAll(originalList.subList(...));
```